# Rewiring 3 way switched receptacle to control the ceiling light

Tags: receptacle

Have a 3 way switch which controls a receptacle. Have an existing ceiling light/fan controlled by pull chains.

I want the 3 way switches to control the ceiling light.

Difficult?  i find the attic difficult to work in. Deep insulation and low height.

Are wireless (non wifi) switches an option?

Comment: How difficult will depend on where the existing wires go. You might be lucky and find that they all route through one of the switch boxes. Or not. (a) Post pictures of inside of both switch boxes and receptacle box; (b) Are the fan & receptacle on the same breaker?

Comment: Can you post photos of the boxes involved? Is surface raceway an acceptable wiring method if new wires need to be run?